# Try to removing empty html tags in C#

Tags: c#, html, xml

i have this html code:

```
    <div class="sfd">test</div>
  <p dir="rtl" style="margin-bottom: 0;margin-left: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-top: 0;"><span style="font-size: 11pt;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;padding: 0;"> </span></p>
  <p dir="rtl" style="font-family: David;font-size: 11pt;line-height: 115.0%;margin-top: 0;"><span style="font-size: 11pt;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;padding: 0;"> </span></p>
  <div class="sfd">test</div>
  <p dir="rtl" style="font-family: David;font-size: 11pt;line-height: 115.0%;margin-bottom: 0;margin-left: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-top: 0;"><span style="font-size: 11pt;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;padding: 0;"> </span></p>
  <p dir="rtl" style="font-family: David;font-size: 11pt;line-height: 115.0%;margin-bottom: 0;margin-left: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-top: 0;"><span style="font-size: 11pt;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;padding: 0;"> </span></p>
  <div class="sfd">test</div>
  <p dir="rtl" style="font-family: David;font-size: 11pt;line-height: 115.0%;margin-right: 0;margin-top: 0;"><span style="font-size: 11pt;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;padding: 0;"> </span></p>
```

I parsing him with:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(html);
```

and i want to remove all empty html tags recursively like that:

```
  <div class="sfd">test</div>
  <div class="sfd">test</div>
  <div class="sfd">test</div>
```

i tried with this one:

```
        xDoc.Descendants()
.Where(e => !e.HasAttributes &&
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value) &&
            e.Descendants().All(f => String.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Value) && !f.HasAttributes))
.Remove();
```

but do nothing

Tnx

Comment: HTML isnt XML. You'd be better off using an HTML Parser.

Comment: i cant add another libaries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check for `Value`. `Value` will also be empty when there are child nodes (that are empty). Also, you are checking for attributes and not removing nodes that have attributes, but from your example you want to remove empty tags with attributes.

```
string src = @"
    <html><body>
    <div class=""sfd"">test</div>
    <p dir = ""rtl"" style=""margin-bottom: 0;margin-left: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-top: 0;""><span style = ""font-size: 11pt;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;padding: 0;"" > </span ></p >
    <p dir=""rtl"" style=""font-family: David;font-size: 11pt;line-height: 115.0%;margin-top: 0;""><span style = ""font-size: 11pt;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;padding: 0;"" > </span ></p >
    <div class=""sfd"">test</div>
    <p dir = ""rtl"" style=""font-family: David;font-size: 11pt;line-height: 115.0%;margin-bottom: 0;margin-left: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-top: 0;""><span style = ""font-size: 11pt;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;padding: 0;"" > </span ></p >
    <p dir=""rtl"" style=""font-family: David;font-size: 11pt;line-height: 115.0%;margin-bottom: 0;margin-left: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-top: 0;""><span style = ""font-size: 11pt;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;padding: 0;"" > </span ></p >
    <div class=""sfd"">test</div>
    <p dir = ""rtl"" style=""font-family: David;font-size: 11pt;line-height: 115.0%;margin-right: 0;margin-top: 0;""><span style = ""font-size: 11pt;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;padding: 0;"" > </span ></p >
    </body></html>
";


XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(src);

xDoc.Descendants().Where(node => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.Value)).Remove();

MessageBox.Show(xDoc.ToString());
```

To keep `<br/>`, just exclude it explicitely. Replace in above code:

```
xDoc.Descendants().Where(node => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.Value) && node.Name != "br").Remove();
```

Comment: Tnx, this is the solving

Comment: @kfir Special handling for `<br/>`

Comment: Nothing changed with the excluding

Comment: @kfir Don't add the line, but use it in the original code. Works for me.

Comment: @kfir Yeah, this will only work when there is actually other text, not only line break.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex to remove, I think this should work:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(html,"<[^/>].*></[^>]+>", "");
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile. `\/`  is not a valid escape sequence in C# string literals. Also, using regular expressions will not satisfy the requirement in all cases. For example. if the source contains `<p><span>keep</span><span></span></p>`, the tags are all deleted even though there is text content

Comment: Oh yeah, backslashes removed. I was testing with his inputs and outputs on regex101. Seemed to work okay for what he needs in the question

Comment: How your regex handle <div><div></div></div> ?

Comment: It removes them as they are empty